# Proportion of data per month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to make a table of data proportion per month

Data:

> Message   | Date       |
>
> bla bla   | 2018-04-10 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-04-11 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-04-12 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-04-13 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-05-13 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-05-14 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-05-15 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-05-16 |
>
> blabla    | 2018-05-17 |

I tried

```
SELECT Date, count(*) as Message, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) as year, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) as month, MIN(Date) as date
FROM `my_table` 
GROUP BY Date, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) as an, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date)
```

I wanted:

> Message   | Date  |
>
> 4         | april |
>
> 5         | may   |

I'm so sorry, I don't know how to put tables here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is limited to this year only then

```
 SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) date , count(*) message from your_table 
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date)
```

For multiple year you can try

```
 SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) as Mnth,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) as yr ,
 count(*) message from your_table 
 GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Message, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS year, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', Date) AS month
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` 
GROUP BY 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date), 
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', Date)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data fro you question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT 'bla bla' Message, DATE '2018-04-10' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-04-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-04-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-04-13' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-05-13' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-05-14' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-05-15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-05-16' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blabla', '2018-05-17' 
)
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Message, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) AS year, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', Date) AS month
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` 
GROUP BY 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date), 
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', Date)
```

with result as

```
Row Message year    month    
1   5       2018    May  
2   4       2018    April
```